# Disable Tap to Click on Haier Y11b

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, tap-to-click

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on [Haier Y11b](http://www.haier.com/pk/products/pc/Tablet_PC/y11b_ext.shtml)
Its touchpad is very bad at guessing tap while we move finger over it.

I want to disable TAP to click, unfortunately this setting is not there in settings there is no checkbox not even label.

I searched for solution, this is what I did.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wget gdebi
wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/synaptiks/kde-config-touchpad_0.8.1-2_all.deb
sudo gdebi kde-config-touchpad_0.8.1-2_all.deb
sudo apt-mark hold kde-config-touchpad=0.8.1-2
```

But at the end it said that there is no synaptics touchpad.

Please note that it is too worse, that I had to attach USB Mouse, 
here is **xinput list** result.

```
engrwarsi@Journal:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AWOOD AWOOD KB + MOUSE                    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AWOOD AWOOD KB + MOUSE                    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera                                id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera                                id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
Here is output of command xinput
~$ xinput list-props 11
Device 'AWOOD AWOOD KB + MOUSE':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (264): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (265):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (266):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (267):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (257):    1241, 57856
    Device Node (258):  "/dev/input/event16"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (268): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (270):  0
    Axis Labels (271):  "Rel X" (149), "Rel Y" (150), "Rel Horiz Wheel" (262), "Rel Vert Wheel" (263)
    Button Labels (272):    "Button Left" (142), "Button Middle" (143), "Button Right" (144), "Button Wheel Up" (145), "Button Wheel Down" (146), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (147), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (148)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (273): 1, 1, 1
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (274):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (275):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (276): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (277): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (278):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (279):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (280):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (281):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (282):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (283):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (284): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (285):  0
```

Now this is output of install

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
[sudo] password for engrwarsi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xserver-xorg-input-libinput
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 88.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 xserver-xorg-input-libinput amd64 0.18.0-1 [25.8 kB]
Fetched 25.8 kB in 1s (15.4 kB/s)                    
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-input-libinput.
(Reading database ... 249283 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../xserver-xorg-input-libinput_0.18.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-input-libinput (0.18.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-input-libinput (0.18.0-1) ...
```

Comment: While I try to post it says that I can't post due to spam from my network and so on :( I don't know why! :(

Comment: Hello! Can you please try this command? `synclient MaxTapTime=0` This should disable tap to click.

Comment: $ synclient MaxTap=0
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

Comment: Ok, can you now also use this command and edit the question with the output? `xinput list-props 11` This should show more info about your touchpad in general

Comment: I used the command and have edited the question!

Comment: Hmm.. maybe this could be of some help: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211112 basically, you just need to install the following package: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput`

Comment: Pretty weird though.. normally mouse stuff should just work out of the box.

Comment: Isn't there anyone who understands this problem?  :(

Comment: Should I assume that this forum is only for those who are highly versed in linux and only for their complex problems, like other forums and revert to windows? 
Since no one seems to give a shit to new users.